# maxMessageLength Flutter grpc

Tags: flutter, dart, grpc

I am using grpc connection method in my Flutter app. but when I try to send large (around 1GB) it doesn`t get the files. I think it is due to maxMessageLength is bigger than limit.
Does anyone have solution for this issue?

```
channel = ClientChannel(
      host,
      port: port,
      options:  const ChannelOptions(
        credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
        connectTimeout: Duration(minutes: 1),

      ),
    );
```

Comment: Perhaps [Set max gRPC message size](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/551)?

Comment: yes, I think so